# Communicate via JSON/REST between ASP.NET 4.5.1 and Oracle Fusion Middleware?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, oracle11g, oracle-fusion-middleware

We have a new ASP.NET 4.5.1 application that needs to interface with Oracle 11g via Oracle Fusion Middleware 11g. My naive preference would be to implement this interface via JSON over REST services.

I am new to Oracle and interoperating with it. It has been difficult to search through years of documentation concerning the technology stack to find a pragmatic answer.

1. Is it possible to communicate via JSON/REST between ASP.NET 4.5.1 and Oracle Fusion Middleware 11g?
2. If so, how difficult is it?
3. If so, is it maintainable?